# Changing 2D element of a list to 1D element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wanted to change 2D element of a list to 1D in the following code.

```
from itertools import chain
a = ['one', 'two']
b = [[1, 2], [3, 3]]
c = [ [[x] * y for x, y in zip(a, row)] for row in b ]
c = list(chain.from_iterable(c))
print(c)
```

The out put was

```
[['one'], ['two', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'one'], ['two', 'two', 'two']]
```

if

```
c = [ [x * y for x, y in zip(a, row)] for row in b ]
```

the result would be

```
[['Amh', 'EngEng'], ['AmhAmhAmh', 'EngEngEng']]
```

But I wanted the result to be as the following using list comprehension.

```
[['one', 'two', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer** (edited in after OP's edit):

Given

```
c = [ [[x] * y for x, y in zip(a, row)] for row in b ]
```

You can simply iterate over the new sublist as you create it:

```
c = [ [i for x, y in zip(a, row) for i in [x]*y] for row in b]
```

or use `itertools.chain` if that's what you prefer:

```
c = [ list(chain.from_iterable([x]*y for x, y in zip(a, row))) for row in b]
```

Output:

```
[['one', 'two', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two']]
```

**Old answer:**

Given

```
lst = [['one'], ['two', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'one'], ['two', 'two', 'two']]
```

You could concatenate lists in a list comprehension using `range`:

```
out = [lst[i] + lst[i+1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
```

or using `zip`:

```
out = [li1+li2 for li1, li2 in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])]
```

Output:

```
[['one', 'two', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two']]
```